# The loadbalancing algorithm on Amazon EC2 loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

We plan to do some performance test on a web site hosted on some Amazon EC2 instances.  The question is,  if all the HTTP traffic come from the same IP addresses (say, in the case of many different client hosts sharing the same public IP),  will the EC2 loadbalancer forward all traffic to only one of the web servers (instances)?

Comment: It is better using a load testing from multiple machines. You can generate more load like this and get more realistic load balancing with ELB.

Comment: Agreed. More machines can generate more load. Unfortunately that's our limitation is that we have generate the load from the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a problem due to DNS caching by clients indeed (see my answer to [Can Elastic Load Balancers correctly distribute traffic to different size instances](https://serverfault.com/a/386527/10305) for more on the previous state of affairs), but has mostly been remedied apparently with the recent introduction of [Elastic Load Balancing [...] Cross-Zone Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/11/06/elastic-load-balancing-adds-cross-zone-load-balancing/):

> We are pleased to announce support for cross-zone load balancing, **which changes the way that Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) routes incoming requests**, making it even easier for you to deploy applications across multiple Availability Zones. *[emphasis mine]*

The announcements provides a bit more information already, but links to [Request Routing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#request-routing) for details:

> If you enable cross-zone load balancing, you no longer have to worry that clients caching DNS information will result in requests being distributed unevenly. And now, **ELB ensures that requests are distributed equally to your back-end instances** regardless of the Availability Zone in which they are located. *[emphasis mine]*

This still doesn't outline the exact algorithm used, but the main source of uneven distribution seems to be addressed like so (I have read a post by a large AWS customer recently, who reported their metrics becoming a more or less flat curve after flipping the switch on this, but don't recall the URL right now).

Comment: Thanks Steffen for additional information.  I am looking an extreme case when all the users will access a web site (hosted in AWS) from the same IP addresses (for example, if the users all share the same public IP).  Wonder whether the ELB will load-balance the requests to different hosts.  Note that there is a catch:  the requests from the same users typically need to be forwarded to the same server instance.  If ELB inserts its own cookie, it can use it to tell whether the requests are from the same user or not.

Answer (score 0):

This has been the case in the past, I presume it still may be an issue. Its not so much that it will forward all traffic to a single instance, but it can send all traffic to a single zone.

The ELB does some load balancing with DNS round robin. A cached DNS lookup, could result in multiple requests being routed to the same zone.

Comment: thanks for the insight. Wonder if there is any link to the description of how the loadbalancer in AWS works. In theory, a loadbalancer can fan out requests from same IP by inserting extra cookies (specific to loadbalancer). Don't know whether it's implemented on the AWS loadbalancers.